# TensorFlow - Shape Mismatch

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have just started with TensorFlow. I was checking out the MusicGenerator available at https://github.com/Conchylicultor/MusicGenerator

I am getting error:

> ValueError: Trying to share variable
>   rnn_decoder/KeyboardCell/Decoder/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/basic_lstm_cell/kernel,
>   but specified shape (1024, 2048) and found shape (525, 2048).

I think this might be due to some variable shared between the encoder and decoder of the cell. The main code was written for tensorflow 0.10.0 but I am trying to run on Tensorflow 1.3

```
def __call__(self, prev_keyboard, prev_state, scope=None):
    """ Run the cell at step t
    Args:
        prev_keyboard: keyboard configuration for the step t-1 (Ground truth or previous step)
        prev_state: a tuple (prev_state_enco, prev_state_deco)
        scope: TensorFlow scope
    Return:
        Tuple: the keyboard configuration and the enco and deco states
    """

    # First time only (we do the initialisation here to be on the global rnn loop scope)
    if not self.is_init:
        with tf.variable_scope('weights_keyboard_cell'):
            # TODO: With self.args, see which network we have chosen (create map 'network name':class)
            self.encoder.build()
            self.decoder.build()

            prev_state = self.encoder.init_state(), self.decoder.init_state()
            self.is_init = True

    # TODO: If encoder act as VAE, we should sample here, from the previous state

    # Encoder/decoder network
    with tf.variable_scope(scope or type(self).__name__):
        with tf.variable_scope('Encoder'):
            # TODO: Should be enco_output, enco_state
            next_state_enco = self.encoder.get_cell(prev_keyboard, prev_state)
        with tf.variable_scope('Decoder'):  # Reset gate and update gate.
            next_keyboard, next_state_deco = self.decoder.get_cell(prev_keyboard, (next_state_enco, prev_state[1]))
    return next_keyboard, (next_state_enco, next_state_deco)
```

I am completely new to RNNs and CNNs . I have been reading a bit about it as well, understood in a high level way on how these work. And understood how some parts of the code is actually working in training, modelling. But I don't think enough to debug this. And especially because I am a bit confused with the tensorflow API as well.

It would be great why this might be happenning, what I can do to fix it. And also if you can point me to some books for CNN, RNN, Back propogation and how to use tensor flow effectively to build things.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Same problem here.